# I have a probability problem - binomial probability

Tags: probability

A tennis player finds that, on average, he gets his serve in in eight out of every ten attempts, and that he serves an ace (a serve which is in the boundaries and not touched by his opponent) once every fifteen serves. He serves four times. Assuming that successive serves are independent events, find the probability that:

1. he hits at least three aces,
2. he hits exactly three aces and the other serve lands in.

**Here is my working for 1.**

Let X be the random variable that is the number of aces for each serve (each Bernoulli stage)

$P(X=3) = {4 \choose 3} (\frac {1}{15})^3(\frac {14}{15}) = 0.001106$

The whole expression is just basically plugging in the formula for Binomial Probability: ${n \choose x}(p^x) (q^{n-x})$ where p stands for the chance of success and q stands for the chance of failure which is simply  $1-p$:  in my situation, the chance of success here is getting an ace.

However, the answer is $0.001126$.

**Here is my working for 2.**

let X be the random variable that is the number of aces for each serve (each Bernoulli stage)

$P(\text{exactly 3 ace, a presumably non-ace serve that is in}) = (\frac {1}{15})^3 * (\frac {14}{15})(\frac {8}{10})*\frac {4P4}{3!} $

The $(\frac {1}{15})^3$ part comes from the fact that we want to get 3 ace first and then the $(\frac {14}{15})(\frac {8}{10})$ comes from the fact we then get a non-ace serve that is in : so by product rule of probability we multiply the chance that we get a non-ace by the chance that we get a serve that is in. But this is one specific ordered outcome where get get 3 ace first, THEN the non-ace in serve. To account for the outcomes with the same elements but different order, I multiplied by $\frac {4P4}{3!}$.

Then the whole thing evaluates to $0.0008849 $

But the answers say $0.000869$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): the answer is $P(X \ge 3) = P(X=3) + P(X=4)$; you forgot to compute the probability that all 4 serves were aces.

---

For (2), your mistake is applying the product rule to events that are not independent (a serve being an ace and being in are dependent, since knowing a serve is an ace implies that the serve is in). Here are two approaches.

### Approach 1

The probability of exactly 3 aces and 1 non-ace is $(1/15)^3 \cdot (14/15) \cdot 4$. You then need to multiply this by the probability that a serve is in *given* it was not an ace.
$$P(\text{in} \mid \text{non-ace}) = \frac{P(\text{in} \cap \text{non-ace})}{P(\text{non-ace)}} = \frac{\frac{8}{10} - \frac{1}{15}}{\frac{14}{15}}
= \frac{11}{14}.$$
This is slightly smaller than $P(\text{in})=8/10$ which explains why the provided answer is slightly smaller than yours.

### Approach 2

The probability of a serve being in but not an ace is $\frac{8}{10} - \frac{1}{15} = \frac{11}{15}$, so the answer is $(1/15)^3 \cdot (11/15) \cdot 4$.